# Wordpress Site RSS Feed link

Tags: wordpress, rss, feedburner

I'm trying to put a link for users to subscribe to my blog using an RSS Feed.

```
<div id="rss_link" style="margin-left:35%; margin-right:20%; width:10em;">
<a href="http://therearenoroads.com/feed">
<img style="width:90px; height:90px;" src="http://blog.sironaconsulting.com/.a/6a00d8341c761a53ef0120a7abc384970b-120wi" alt="RSS   Link" />
</div>
<p style="font-size:1.3em; text-align:center;">Feed of TANR Knowledge</p>
</a>
```

This is the error that appears on the link...

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

...then a whole bunch of code.

Any ideas where this problem could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't so much an error as it as a note regarding how your feed will be presented. It's letting you know that your feed isn't being styled and is being output in a raw form. That isn't necessarily "bad", since it will still work as a RSS feed. It just won't be as pretty. Compare: http://news.google.com/?output=rss (a valid RSS feed with no styling) with http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml?edition=int (styled RSS)

Comment: On the user end I believe there are "feed reader" extensions that will handle this for them, but I haven't used these myself.

Answer (score 1):

You are closing `</div>` inside your `<a>` element. You might want something like this:

```
<div id="rss_link" style="margin-left:35%; margin-right:20%; width:10em;">
    <a href="http://therearenoroads.com/feed">
        <img style="width:90px; height:90px;" src="http://blog.sironaconsulting.com/.a/6a00d8341c761a53ef0120a7abc384970b-120wi" alt="RSS   Link" />    
        <p style="font-size:1.3em; text-align:center;">Feed of TANR Knowledge</p>
    </a>
</div>
```

Additionally, this also happens in chrome when you click on most rss feeds, since it doesn't have a rss subscribe widget in it. In firefox, the feed is handled much more smoothly.